# Randomize a value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, slider

That slider FancyTransitions does not support random effects. So to work around that I need the value for `effect: 'curtain'` to be random either which can be "curtain", "zipper",  or "wave". Unless there's a better work around.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#slideshowHolder').jqFancyTransitions({
        width: 500, // width of panel
        height: 333, // height of panel
        strips: 10, // number of strips
        delay: 4000, // delay between images in ms
        stripDelay: 50, // delay beetwen strips in ms
        titleOpacity: 0.7, // opacity of title
        titleSpeed: 1000, // speed of title appereance in ms
        position: 'alternate', // top, bottom, alternate, curtain
        direction: 'random', // left, right, alternate, random, fountain, fountainAlternate
        effect: 'curtain', // curtain, zipper, wave
        navigation: false, // prev next and buttons
        links : false // show images as links                                                   });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what's the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: i need it to change for each slide not on page load!

Comment: Oh, sounds like you need to override the FT's slide change function and embed your random-generator code there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
effect: ['curtain', 'zipper', 'wave'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
```

?

Comment: Yep, but that changes only when i reload page, i need it to change while script is running (slider sliding).

Comment: @JohnA So, doesn't it suffice to to call `$('#slideshowHolder').jqFancyTransitions({...` again? So you simply reapply the `jqFancyTransitions` with different `effect` on the same div `#slideshowHolder`, whenever you feel you want to...?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
var effect;
var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);

if (i==1) effect = "curtain";
if (i==2) effect = "zipper";
if (i==3) effect = "wave";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var effects = ["curtain", "zipper", "wave"];

$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#slideshowHolder').jqFancyTransitions({
    ...
    effect: effects[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)], // curtain, zipper, wave
    ...
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work either i need it to change for each slide not on page load!

Answer (score 0):

plugin doesn't have a callback for transitions so you need to modify it to allow randomizing the effect parameter.

adding `params.effect = ['curtain', 'zipper', 'wave'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];` to the top of the `$.transition` function in plugin code would randomly set the effect parameter on each transition. not tested but this should be the way.

i strongly recommend using a better slideshow plugin like [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) or [nivo-slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) though.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that. IMHO this is best slider its light weight and transitions look awsome. Cycle is non professional and nivo-slider is good however its heavyweight and has so many unnecessary things

Comment: by heavyweight i mean size of files user have to download and performance on slow computers are bad